# How to format the result when using Jersey to develop RESTful Web Service?

Tags: xml, json, format, jersey

I use Jersey to develop RESTful Web Service, but the result xml and json string is not well formated, it's hard to read. How do I format the result xml and json string? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What type of xml support do you use? If it's JAXB, then you can use annotations, if you work with low level xml classes such SAX or DOM Source, then use it's methods.